# How to make custom border design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make layout similar to this image.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 10.0),
                      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 2),
                      right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 2),
                      bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 2),
                    ),
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(15)
                        )),
              ),
              onTap: () => {},
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why but *borderRadius* only works when specifying *border* with Border.all else it crashes..

Maybe this workaround can get the job done for you..

```
 GestureDetector(
   child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
     new Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
       width: double.infinity,
       height: 100.0,
       decoration: new BoxDecoration(
         border: new Border.all(
             color: Colors.grey[300],
             width: 2.0,
             style: BorderStyle.solid),
         borderRadius: new BorderRadius.horizontal(
           right: new Radius.circular(20.0),
         ),
       ),
     ),
     Container(
         width: 10,
         height: 100,
         margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
         color: Colors.blue),
   ]),
 )
```